# How to configure the Nekohtml html parser to turn <br> into <br />

Tags: java, html, xhtml, html-parsing, neko

I'm evaluating the Nekothml parser among other Java HTML parsers, and I'm trying to make it replace all my `<br>` with `<br />` elements. Can this be done using the Nekohtml API?
Any feedback is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The nekohtml parser is a *parser*. It produces a DOM tree or SAX events, all in memory, not text. If you have configured it properly, it will read the html <br> as if it were an empty XML element, and any XML serialization will them produce <br/>.